# How to view deleted files of Azure Storage Lifecycle management?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have lifecycle management enabled on Azure Blob Storage Container. It worked for several months. Currently I need to see what blobs have been deleted by the lifecycle management rules during this time(as much as is still available). Is there something like a history or log for lifecycle management?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such history or logs feature available for now. You can enable [Storage Analytical logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics) and that will have details of each and every operation. If lifecycle management policy has deleted any blobs, the User agent for those operation will be something like Object Life Cycle.(but it will be only for the upcoming operations)

If you wish you may leave your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage) All the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.